# Any short URL service that you can POST variables on?

Tags: url, variables, post, redirect, get

I work for a small SMS marketing company, where we're sending out text message that each contain a unique code for the user (as a variable). My url is rather long, and I want to attach a unique variable for each one.

For example, the full URL might be:

http://www.mybigwebsiteurlishuge.com/more/more/?code={variable}

but I want it to be something like:

http://bit.ly/2398h?code={variable}

Anybody know any services that can do this? Otherwise I need to purchase small domain name just for this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Most shortening services have APIs that you can use to shorten your URLs. Including bit.ly. Yu will have to use their API to the shortened URL.

Answer (score 0):

I kept on looking, and still couldn't find anything suitable, so I got a new 3-character domain name, and also make a redirecting script that changed miniaturized variable names t the full ones. This works just as good really.